# INSERT INTO .... Multiple Rows ... On Duplicate Key

Tags: mysql, key, rows

I have a mysql database for a web commerce site with a pricing table that looks like this :

```
priceid (int, PK, AI)
productid (int)
membershipid (int)
price (decimal(12,2))
quantity (int)
```

This allows items to have different levels of pricing either based on `membershipid` or `quantity` (but here the value will always be 1).

I need to be updating this with a source table like :

```
productid (int,PK)
price1 (int)
price2 (int)
price3 (int)
```

I'm not sure how to Insert the data :

```
COLS:[productid, price, membershipid, quantity][priceid]
ROWS:[productid, price1, 1, 1][n]
ROWS:[productid, price2, 2, 1][n]
ROWS:[productid, price3, 5, 1][n]
```

(*n = ID on new insert, or PK Update if it already exists)*
I know the following code won't work, but essentially, what I need to do is this :

```
INSERT INTO mysql.pricing
    (prouductid, membershipid, quantity, price) 
SELECT productid, 1, 1, price1 from mysql.source 'row n
SELECT productid, 2, 1, price2 from mysql.source 'row n+1
SELECT productid, 5, 1, price3 from mysql.source 'row n+2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE productid = VALUES(productid),membershipid = VALUES(membership), quantity = VALUES(quantity), price = VALUES(price);
```

I need three distinct rows, each with the same [productid], but differing [priceid, membershipid, price].

I've searched for answers and been banging my head against a desk for days.
Any ideas? Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have mentioned priceid (int, PK, AI)-  You can use on duplicate key update in     primary key but not on Auto Increment.  

There are two ways to solve this:  
Remove only Auto Increment from priceid and set the field as     (productid,membershipid,pricenumber) eg:  
Membershipid = 2   
productid = 33   
price1 = 11   
price2 = 12  
price3 = 13  
**priceid will be**  
33211 (price 1)  
33212 (price 2)  
33213 (price 3)  

This will always be unique...(for primary key), updating the following info.  
for memebershipid 2 , productid 33, price1 = 25, price2 = 28, price3 = 30

insert will be as follows (priceid,membershipid,productid,price,quantity)
```

`replace into mysql.pricing values(33211,33,2,25,1);`
`replace into mysql.pricing values(33222,33,2,28,1);`
`replace into mysql.pricing values(33233,33,2,30,1);`

```
if the price2 has been changed from 28 to 29 you insert statment will be like this.
```

`replace into mysql.pricing values(33222,33,2,29,1);`

```
(using replace instead of insert for update incase of already existing primary key) 

or

other way is add another column in you mysql.pricing table with datetime, and priceid     will be primarykey  & autoincrement

mysql table columns 
priceid (int, PK, AI),productid (int),membershipid (int) price(decimal(12,2)),quantity     (int),insert_date (datetime)

Above insert can be inserted as following using now() function (which returns current     date& time)
```

`insert into mysql.pricing values(33,2,25,1,now());`
`insert into mysql.pricing values(33,2,28,1,now());`
`insert into mysql.pricing values(33,2,30,1,now());`

```
updating  price2 (it will always be insert)
```

`insert into mysql.pricing values(33,2,29,1,now());`

```
make all  fetch result based on max insert_date(datetime field) for respective     membershipid,price1/price2..  
Hope this solves your problem.
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's difficult for me to decipher what you mean in the first method. After removing AI I would run this 3 times, each with the different membershipID ?? : REPLACE INTO mysql.pricing (priceid, prouductid, membershipid, quantity, price) SELECT priceid, productid, 1, 1, priceA from mysql.source